# Can't install PymuPDF although python Libary have PymuPDF

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pymupdf

I tried to install PyMuPDF on Python 3.9 when first I installed by pip install PymuPDF and re-checked by pip list like this"

But when I imported PyMuPDF:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMuPDF'
```

Next, I tried to install PymuPDF from doc, it said I need install MuPDF first, and install with Wheel, I tried both:
`pip install C:\Users\Admin\Desktop/PyMuPDF-1.19.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` and `pip install PyMuPDF-1.19.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` but reviced error:

```
 yMuPDF-1.19.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What should i do to install `PyMuPDF`, thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it looks like you are incorrectly importing the module. The pymupdf module is imported as follows:

```
import fitz
```

Not "import pymupdf" as you did in the code provided. The history behind this is given in the documentation: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

PyMuPDF is available with a wheel under all Windows versions - you should have no problem at all.
But please follow this procedure:

1. Make sure your pip is the current one. This ensures that any changes in supported platform tags are known to pip.
2. Then install PyMuPDF.

So overall

```
py -3.10 -m pip install -U pip
py -3.10 -m pip install -U pymupdf
```

This should simply work!
In your script however you must do `import fitz` - this is the top-level name of the package.